# need to enable reactive form without firing validation

Tags: angular

i worken on reactive anguar form and i need to disable form controls before save and after save i reset form and enable it

i faced a problem because enable form fire form validation and i need to enable form without firing validation

my submit function

```
 onSubmit(){
    debugger
    if(this.addForm.valid){
      this.addForm.disable();
      this.showFooter=true;
      this.showFooterSave=false;
    }
  }
```

after save function

```
resetForm(){
       this.addForm.reset();
       this.addForm.enable();
}
```

Comment: Use a fieldset with `disabled` bound to some property which becomes `true` when there is a submitting process. Thus user cannot interact with the form while it's being processed

Comment: how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's imagine that is your form markup

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup] (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <!-- Here we set a fieldset -->
  <fieldset [disabled]="submitting">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    <input type="text" formControlName="wish">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <fieldset>
</form>
```

And a component.ts

```
...
submitting = false;

...

submit() {
  this.submitting = true;

  this.myService.submitForm(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(
  () => {
    console.log('Hooray the form was submitted!');
    this.submitting = false;
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
    this.submitting = false;
  }
  );
}
...
```

Disabled fieldset prohibits user interaction with the form controls including buttons. Also, you can make

```
if (this.submitting) {
  return;
}
```

At the beginning of your submit function for the case if user somehow overcame and pressed the submit once again (the formGroup doesn't matter in that case since its value was already read and sent to the server so no harm).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem also, just added this line:

```
  this.formControl.markAsUntouched();
```